# Jumping simulation stop falling when returned to ground

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to simulate a jump in a Rect.

I set the KEYDOWN  and KEYUP events and K_SPACE button to simulate the jump.

My difficulty is stopping the returning fall when the rect reaches the ground (using cordX).

I realize that will not work and comment it out in the GAME_BEGIN statement.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400,300))
pygame.display.set_caption("shield hacking")
JogoAtivo = True
GAME_BEGIN = False
# Speed in pixels per frame
speedX = 0
speedY = 0
cordX = 10
cordY = 100
jumping=False;
run=False;


def draw():
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    quadrado = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), (cordX, cordY ,50, 52))
    pygame.display.flip();



while JogoAtivo:
    for evento in pygame.event.get():
        print(evento)
    #verifica se o evento que veio eh para fechar a janela
        if evento.type == pygame.QUIT:
               JogoAtivo = False
               pygame.quit();
        if evento.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if evento.key == pygame.K_a:
                   print('GAME BEGIN')
                   GAME_BEGIN = True
                   draw();        
        if evento.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if evento.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                   speedX=-0.006
                   run= True;
        if evento.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
             if evento.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                   speedX=0.006
                   run= True;
        if evento.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
             if evento.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                   speedY=-0.090
                   jumping= True;
        if evento.type == pygame.KEYUP:
             if evento.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                   speedY=+0.090
                   jumping= True;


    if GAME_BEGIN:
        if not jumping:
            gravity = cordX;
        """if gravity == cordY:
            speedY=0;"""
        cordX+=speedX
        cordY+=speedY
        draw()
```

> > > UPDATED BELOW

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400,300))
pygame.display.set_caption("shield hacking")
JogoAtivo = True
GAME_BEGIN = False
# Speed in pixels per frame
speedX = 0
speedY = 0
cordX = 10
cordY = 100
groundX=0;
groundY=150;
jumping=False;
run=False;


def draw():
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    ground = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 255, 0), (groundX, groundY,400, 10))
    quadrado = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), (cordX, cordY ,50, 52))
    pygame.display.flip();



while JogoAtivo:
    for evento in pygame.event.get():
        print(evento)
    #verifica se o evento que veio eh para fechar a janela
        if evento.type == pygame.QUIT:
               JogoAtivo = False
               pygame.quit();
        if evento.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if evento.key == pygame.K_a:
                   print('GAME BEGIN')
                   GAME_BEGIN = True
                   draw();        
            if evento.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                   speedX=-0.006
                   run= True;
            if evento.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                   speedX=0.006
                   run= True;
            if evento.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                   speedY=-0.090
                   jumping= True;
        if evento.type == pygame.KEYUP:
             if evento.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                   speedY=+0.090
                   jumping= True;


    if GAME_BEGIN:
        cordX+=speedX
        cordY+=speedY
        draw();
        if cordY +50>= groundY:
            speedY=0
            jumping=False;
```

Comment: BTW: you don't have to repeat `if evento.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:` - it makes code less readable.

Comment: in `KEYUP, K_SPACE` you set `jumping=True` so you keep jumping - and you don't have rule which decide when stop jumping (or rather "falling") - ie. `if cordY <= groundY: jumping = False`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done what was suggested in the comments. Here is my fixed code

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400,300))
pygame.display.set_caption("shield hacking")
JogoAtivo = True
GAME_BEGIN = False
# Speed in pixels per frame
speedX = 0
speedY = 0
cordX = 10
cordY = 100
groundX=0;
groundY=150;
jumping=False;
run=False;


def draw():
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    ground = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 255, 0), (groundX, groundY,400, 10))
    quadrado = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), (cordX, cordY ,50, 52))
    pygame.display.flip();



while JogoAtivo:
    for evento in pygame.event.get():
        print(evento)
    #verifica se o evento que veio eh para fechar a janela
        if evento.type == pygame.QUIT:
               JogoAtivo = False
               pygame.quit();
        if evento.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if evento.key == pygame.K_a:
                   print('GAME BEGIN')
                   GAME_BEGIN = True
                   draw();        
            if evento.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                   speedX=-0.006
                   run= True;
            if evento.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                   speedX=0.006
                   run= True;
            if evento.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                   speedY=-0.090
                   jumping= True;
        if evento.type == pygame.KEYUP:
             if evento.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                   speedY=+0.090
                   jumping= True;


    if GAME_BEGIN:
        cordX+=speedX
        cordY+=speedY
        draw();
        if cordY +50>= groundY:
            speedY=0
            jumping=False;
```

Comment: BTW: much more complex [platform jumper](http://programarcadegames.com/python_examples/show_file.php?file=platform_jumper.py)